# Why does xmlGetProp substitute character entity references when reading attribute values?

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

I'm using *libxml2* to parse/read an HTML page. The following code is used to read the value of an attribute:

```c
char *value = (char*)xmlGetProp(node, attr->name);
```

But `xmlGetProp` substitutes character entity references when it reads the attribute content. E.g.

```
<p onload="readId=&quot;blahString&quot;; myFun();"> Event handler in P HTML TAG</p>
```

In the above case, it returns the following string as "onload" attribute value:

```
readId="blahString";myFun();
```

The character entity reference is substituted in the above reading process. Is there any way to read the attribute value keeping the original HTML content using *libxml2*?

Answer (score 0):

What you call "HTML encoding" is actually called *character entity reference*. To answer your question: No, the [HTML parser](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/tree/HTMLparser.c) of *libxml2* has no option to turn off substitution of character references.

The XML parser keeps character entity references by default, but it can't be used for typical HTML documents.